# Active Directory Users can't login if enablePasswordRetrieval is set to "false" DotNetNuke

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, web-config, dotnetnuke

it looks very strange. But when I tried to set the enablePasswordRetrieval to false then all active directory users can't login anymore on the system. When I reverted back the enablePasswordRetrieval to true then they can login. My problem is, I only want to set the enablePasswordRetrieval to false so that Only enablePasswordReset="true" will trigger.

This is my web.config file (Its working fine when both Active Directory and DNN will log in)

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
     type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
     connectionStringName="SiteSqlServer" 
     enablePasswordRetrieval="true" 
     enablePasswordReset="true" 
     requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
     minRequiredPasswordLength="1" 
     minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
     requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
     passwordFormat="Encrypted" 
     applicationName="DotNetNuke" description="Stores and retrieves membership data from the local Microsoft SQL Server database" />
```

I updated the code to:

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
     type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
     connectionStringName="SiteSqlServer" 
     enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
     enablePasswordReset="true" 
     requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
     minRequiredPasswordLength="1" 
     minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
     requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
     passwordFormat="Encrypted" 
     applicationName="DotNetNuke" description="Stores and retrieves membership data from the local Microsoft SQL Server database" />
```

On that code, I can login using DNN accounts but not on Active Directory Accounts. Any Idea? I just changed the enablePasswordRetrieval to false and now, a disaster happened (can't login using directory accounts). Please help me. Let me know if there is something to configure on the web config.

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to figure out what was wrong?